# "Invalid input syntax for integer" using strapi

Tags: node.js, typescript, strapi, endpoint, insomnia

I'm trying to make a custom enpoint using strapi the problem is that every time I try to run it, on insomnia I have an InternalServerError and in vs code I have the next error:

```
[2024-03-28 15:21:41.180] error: select "t0".* from "public"."reservations" as "t0" where ("t0"."id" = $1) limit $2 - syntax input is not valid for integer type: "getReservationList"
error: select "t0".* from "public"."reservations" as "t0" where ("t0"."id" = $1) limit $2 - input syntax is not valid for type integer: «getReservationList»
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Trabajo\reservant\reservant-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Trabajo\reservant\reservant-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Trabajo\reservant\reservant-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Trabajo\reservant\reservant-be\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:341:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:278:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
[2024-03-28 15:21:41.183] http: GET /api/reservations/getReservationList (60 ms) 500
```

I tried to delete the DDBB, change the authorization code and changing the method's name just in case it creates a conflict with autogenerated endpoints of strapi.

I use this file as route:

```
export default {
    routes: [
        { // Path defined with a URL parameter
            method: 'GET',
            path: "/reservation/getReservationList",
            handler: "reservation.getReservationList"
        },
    ],
}
```

This is the full controller function:

```
async getReservationList(ctx, next) {
    try {

        console.log("enters to the endpoint")

        //Get username from JWT token
        const { id } = await strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.getToken(ctx)
        ctx.state.user = await strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.user.fetchAuthenticatedUser(id);
        let username = ctx.state.user.username;

        //fetch user-profile id from username
        const userProfileEntry = await strapi.db.query("api::user-profile.user-profile").findOne({
            select: ["id"],
            where: { nickname: username },
            populate: false,
        });

        let confirmedEntries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
            "api::reservation.reservation",
            {
                fields: ["full_name", "phone_number", "date", "time", "no_of_people", "status"],
                populate: {
                    author: {
                        fields: ["nickname"]
                    },
                    restaurant: {
                        fields: ["name"]
                    }
                },

                sort: { date: 'desc' },
                filters: {
                    status: "Confirmed",
                    author: userProfileEntry.id
                }
            }
        )


        let pendingEntries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
            "api::reservation.reservation",
            {
                fields: ["full_name", "phone_number", "date", "time", "no_of_people", "status"],
                populate: {
                    author: {
                        fields: ["nickname"]
                    },
                    restaurant: {
                        fields: ["name"]
                    }
                },

                sort: { date: 'desc' },
                filters: {
                    status: "Pending",
                    author: userProfileEntry.id
                }
            }
        )

        let canceledEntries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
            "api::reservation.reservation",
            {
                fields: ["full_name", "phone_number", "date", "time", "no_of_people", "status"],
                populate: {
                    author: {
                        fields: ["nickname"]
                    },
                    restaurant: {
                        fields: ["name"]
                    }
                },

                sort: { date: 'desc' },
                filters: {
                    status: "Canceled",
                    author: userProfileEntry.id
                }
            }
        )

        const entries = confirmedEntries.concat(pendingEntries, canceledEntries)

        let entriesReduced;
        if (entries && Array.isArray(entries)) {
            entriesReduced = entries.reduce((acc, item) => {
                acc = acc || [];
                acc.push({
                    id: item?.id,
                    full_name: item?.full_name || "",
                    phone_number: item?.phone_number || "",
                    date: new Date(item.date).toDateString() || "",
                    time: item?.time || "",
                    no_of_people: item?.no_of_people || "",
                    status: item?.status || "",
                    author: item.author?.nickname || "",
                    restaurant: item.restaurant?.name || "",
                });
                return acc;
            }, []);
        }

        // Return the reduced data
        return entriesReduced;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the `console.log` not printing, it seems like it's a PostgresSQL error. If you look at the stack trace, the error comes from `pg-protocol`. It could be the database query on this custom endpoint is expecting an `id` parameter of type `integer` also a `limit` parameter of type `integer` and in reality it might be getting those parameters or the parameters don't have the correct types for the SQL query.
Can you share the `getReservationList` endpoint code to give us the full picture.

Comment: I added the full controller function

Comment: Making a note: a possible problem after we've fixed the current is your function uses "ctx" parameter, so you should use that variable to send a response from the server. In the current code state, I don't think returning from the function will actually do anything with the server response. This bit: `return entriesReduced;` and `return err`.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace again, the issue is probably with the first db query to the `reservations` entity which is for `confirmedEntries`. I am focusing on that to debug the problem. The first line with this: `strapi.entityService.findMany(`. I would recommend breaking the function down into it's smallest form and correctly returning out of the controller endpoint using `ctx` eg `ctx.send(entriesReduced)` to make sure you can get a HTTP 200 response. You could even remove the `findMany` invocations entirely to help you debug and establish that the controller function is being called.